# Different number of enqueued messages between queue and its corresponding mirror

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

We have an ActiveMQ cluster with 2 nodes. We want to have a mirror queue to forward all messages sent to a specific queue to its mirror one. The following config is used for clustering which uses broker static discovery:

Node1:

```xml
<networkConnectors>
  <networkConnector uri="static://(tcp://node2:61617)?useExponentialBackOff=false"
    name="node1-node2"
    userName="cluster"
    password="12345678"
    duplex="false"
    networkTTL="2"
    decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
    conduitSubscriptions="true"
    suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true"
  />
</networkConnectors>
```

Node2:

```xml
<networkConnectors>
  <networkConnector uri="static://(tcp://node1:61617)?useExponentialBackOff=false"
    name="node2-node1"
    userName="cluster"
    password="12345678"
    duplex="false"
    networkTTL="2"
    decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
    conduitSubscriptions="true"
    suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true"
  />
</networkConnectors>
```

There is no issue in clustering and everything is working fine.
Here's the configuration for mirroring:

```xml
<destinationInterceptors>
    <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
            <compositeQueue name="myqueue" forwardOnly="false">
                <forwardTo>
                    <queue physicalName="myqueueMirror" />
                </forwardTo>
            </compositeQueue>
        </virtualDestinations>
    </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

It is expected the number of messages in `Messages Enqueued` column be the same in both queues. But the issue is that the enqueued number of messages in mirrored queue `myqueueMirror` is higher than the original queue `myqueue`! i.e the number of enqueued messages in `myqueue` is 10000 but the number of enqueued messages in `myqueueMirror` is 10350! I can also see repeated messages in mirrored queue which occurs only one in the main queue.
Any help is appreciated

Update:
The connection protocol is STOMP and the producer code is written in Python

I Googled about the issue but nothing's found.

Comment: What transaction mode are you using?

Comment: If you mean messages are persistent or not, both persistent and non-persistent modes were tested but the result was the same.

Comment: Sorry-- I meant acknowledgement mode. Are you using AUTO_ACK or SESSION_TRANSACTED?  Perhaps another producer sending to the target queues?

Comment: The AUTO_ACK mode is used. Yes there are several producer on the main queue `myqyeye` and several consumer on mirrored queue. I also added the protocol and programming language to my question if it helps

Comment: I don't suspect an ActiveMQ issue-- and this starts getting out-of-scope for a SO question, because it requires a bit of troubleshooting. I suggest starting with looking at what messageIds do not match between the queues and see if you can track back where they originated.